# Name for non-normalized survival plot

Tags: terminology

Survival curves can be plotted with the y axis labeled in probability (i.e., an empirical complementary cumulative distribution function) or in actual counts without normalizing to 1.  Is there a standard terminology to name the latter?  (Bonus points if this terminology can also be used (with a sign change) to non-normalized ecdfs, i.e. the "increasing" version.)

This is strictly a terminology question; the reason is that we are considering to add an ec(c)df plotting function to [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) and, for practicality of use, I would (perhaps?) like the API to be something like `plt.ecdf(data, type="ecdf"/"eccdf"/"non-normalized-ecdf"/"non-normalized-eccdf")` (where the last two names would be replaced by whatever is suggested here), rather than `plt.ecdf(data, complementary=False/True, normalized=False/True)` (which is quite a mouthful to type).